# R - stringdist cost setting error

Tags: r, string-matching, levenshtein-distance, stringdist

I have an error when I try to set the operations costs in

```
stringdist
```

Any ideas why ?

```
library(stringdist)

seq = rbind(
  c('aaa'), 
  c('aba'), 
  c('aab'), 
  c('ccc')
)
```

This works perfectly (Levensthein distance)

```
stringdistmatrix(a = seq, b = seq, method = 'lv')
```

When I want to set the costs (substitution twice the indel)

```
stringdistmatrix(a = seq, b = seq, method = 'lv', weight = c(1,1,2,0))
```

I have this error

```
Error: all(weight > 0) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?stringdistmatrix`.  Specifically, read what it says by the weights argument.  You'll see `Weights must be positive and not exceed 1`.  In this case, the error is telling you that one weight is not positive.  You have one of the weights set to 0.

Once you fix that, you'll still get an error because you have another weight that exceeds 1.

```
stringdistmatrix(a = seq, b = seq, method = 'lv', weight = c(1,1,2,1))
# Error: all(weight <= 1) is not TRUE
```

So, you have to fix that, too.  Keep the weights positive and not above 1.

For example

```
stringdistmatrix(a = seq, b = seq, method = 'lv', weight = c(1,1,1,1))
stringdistmatrix(a = seq, b = seq, method = 'lv', weight = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
```

Comment: Thanks ! dont hate me ;) Some days it's hard to focus.